# How to specify c drive in a dockerfile (windows image)

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am packing a windows app to be a image. The directory looks like this, and because of I need to use absolute path for this image, I have to copy files to base image's c drive.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/framework/aspnet:4.8

COPY . C:\

WORKDIR C:\somefolder
```

But I found that this is not feasible. Are there any better ways to access base image's c drive?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

copy files from local disk to docker image
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ht4gqt4zSyw